# Using css in JavaFX projects

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have a `.css` file with some styles for labels. This is a piece of this file:

```
#defaultBeforeAndNowLabel {
    -fx-background-color: "C4BA62";
    -fx-text-fill: blue;
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-font-size: 1.3em;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

#changedLabelBefore {
    -fx-font-size: 1.5em;
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

#changedLabelNow {
    -fx-font-size: 1.5em;
    -fx-background-color: lawngreen;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

In code I use something like this:

```
label.setId("changedLabelBefore");
```

It works, but there are too much duplicate in `.css` file and I think I can use something like inheritance to avoid it. How can I change my `.css` file and how to use it in java code?

Comment: This is a russian version: ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/441736/Изменение-gui-в-рантайме-используя-css

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use classes instead of IDs.

The .css file can look something like

```
.defaultLabel {
  -fx-alignment: center;
  -fx-font-weight: bold;
  …
}

.defaultLabelBefore {
  -fx-text-fill: black;
  -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

The according java code would look like

```
Label.getStyleClass.addAll(“defaultLabel”, “defaultLabelBefore”);
```

Comment: Ok, what if I want to use different font sizes for both of them? If I apply first style, then second style, my font size will be like it's declared in first style. How to work with it? Remove first style and then add a second? (If they have only the same parameners)

Comment: The second class should override all properties which are declared in both classes. If you have 2 nearly same classes in which only one thing is different then declare all the equivalent stuff at one class and the non equivalent one in another.

Comment: If i declare a styleClass (suppose "defaultLabel") in fxml I can't change it in code using label.getStyleClass.removeIf(s -> s.equals("defaultLabel")); It removes from this list, but it doesn't change a view and I can't replace any styles defined in defaultLabel. It works only if I add defaultLabel in code (w/o using fxml). How can I change styles which are defined in fxml?